# How to create a function whose harmonic is a sine wave

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, functional-equations, harmonic-functions

How do I solve the following equation for $f(\cdot)$?

$f(x)+\frac{1}{n}f(nx)=\sin(x)$

That is, how do I create a function which, when combined with its nth harmonic, will be a sine wave?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{-1}{n})^{k-1}\sin(n^kx)$$

Comment: Can you provide details on how to solve this or point me to somewhere with more information?  I'd like to learn more.

Comment: @mrplants $$f(x)+\frac{1}{n}f(nx)=\sin(x)\\ \frac{1}{n}f(nx)+\frac{1}{n^2}f(n^2x)=\frac{1}{n}\sin(nx) \\\frac{1}{n^2}f(n^2x)+\frac{1}{n^3}f(n^3x)=\frac{1}{n^2} \sin(x) \\\...$$Now, first equation minus second plus third and so on...

Comment: That's amazing.  Thank you.

Comment: Does this function have a name or any special properties?  Anywhere I can learn more about this?

Comment: Okay, walked through it on paper and just have a small edit: the answer is actually $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^k\sin(n^kx)$

Comment: Of course, this is only one solution.  There could be additional solutions where $f(n^k x)/n^k$ does not converge to $0$.